# link to another section on same page

Tags: html, sections

I have lets say 4 sections on my page. Each section has a dropdown arrow link which is placed in an `<a></a>` tag within the section tag `<section></section>` linking to each others `id's`.

For some reason my first dropdown tag is not working. I just cant explain why , what am i missing?

I felt like im miss spelling the `id` or incorrect placing of the `a` tag but all seems to look right, got me confused.

This is my code:

```html
<section>

  <section id="home">
    <div>
      <section id="top">
        {content}
      </section>

      <a href="#section1" class="slidTonext"></a>

    </div>
  </section>

  <section id="section1">
    <div>
      <section id="mid">
        {content}
      </section>

      <a href="#section2" class="slidTonext"></a>

    </div>
  </section>

  <section id="section2">
    <div>
      <section id="bot">
        {content}
      </section>
    </div>
  </section>

</section>
```

For some reason  `href="#section1"` is not working but then the section bellow `href="#section2"`  does work. Confused, what can i be missing here?

Comment: The reason must be somewhere else (js/html/css) what you show works without any problems. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/m5ug0omy/

Comment: Most probably right @caramba , i just added an `id` to the first `div` within `<section id="section1">` and there it scrolls if adding the `id` to the a tag. ill have a deeper look at this. Still so confused.

Comment: Refer https://designshack.net/tutorialexamples/ScrollLinks/internallinks.html#headline4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the name of ***section1*** to something else.

Comment: you guys going not going to like this, but for some reason and im not the only guy working on these files, the section had php code within it and in my editor was not fullscreen and broke the section in to parts, after reading this i went to try change and realised there is 2 `id's` witin the section. problem solved. So it was a flippen basic html error, thanks.